# How to implement Different format for 1 field in jqgrid

Tags: php, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have table configuration for my site like this in **JQGRID**

```
configid config rule

1. Aplication_name 'MyApps'
2. Max number  1,000,00
3. Application End 12/31/2012
```

One cell type's **number** but other's date. And If User want to edit **date** type , it shown **datepicker**. 
How Do I Do that?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to use the jQuery UI datepicker with jqGrid on the [demo page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) under `Integrations` | `UI Datepicker`.

Is there a problem with that demo or something more that you need the grid to achieve?

Comment: and `3. Its not just datepicker problem,how to apply diffrent format in different row (number,date,text)?`